# how to use the variable ${variable} which defined in application.yml in log4j2.xml

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I encountered the same problem as [ApplicationListeners between ConfigFileApplicationListener and LoggingApplicationListener](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2543), the purpose is to use the variable `${variable}` which defined in `application.yml` in `log4j2.xml`.But in the `spring boot 2.0` uses `log4j2`, the `LoggingApplicationListener` order is still before the `ConfigFileApplicationListener`.

pom like

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <!--use log4j2-->
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!--Needed for Async Logging with Log4j 2 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.lmax</groupId>
        <artifactId>disruptor</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

log4j2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration status="warn">
<properties>
    <property name="baseDir">${log.path}</property>
    <property name="appName">${spring.application.name}</property>
</properties>
```

Comment: It seems that only using system environment properties at log4j.xml configuration. Also maybe cannot using application properties.

Comment: I try to use lookup interface, it work fine. Maybe use environment properties is much easier to migrate another project. But increased difficulty of deployment.These two methods are more tangled.